# Django-cms mod_wsgi Compiled vs runtime python version

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apache2

I am an apache novice... that being said. I'm trying to run through a tutorial for configuring django-cms. Everything works well enough when I'm using manage.py 's runserver, but now I want to run this using apache on my local network. I have a server with apache configured using only default settings. Otherwise, I added the following to my sites-available:

```
#blog.conf
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    # For Django
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/blog/blog/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess blog python-path=/var/www/html/blog:/home/{me}/.virtualenvs/cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup blog
    <Directory /var/www/html/blog>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
        Allow from localhost
        Allow from 192.168
        Allow from 10
        Satisfy Any
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I followed that up with:

```
sudo a2ensite blog.conf
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

and finally

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

All without error.

However, pointing my browser at {server IP}:8000 gives me an error. No biggy as I figure I'd messed something up anyway. I tried to diagnose the issue and read the log file:

```
[Sun Oct 02 22:23:28.525648 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7498] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Oct 02 22:23:29.670022 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7639] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Sun Oct 02 22:23:29.670218 2016] [wsgi:warn] [pid 7639] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Sun Oct 02 22:23:29.676669 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7639] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Oct 02 22:23:29.676782 2016] [core:notice] [pid 7639] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Which seemed to be telling me that the my version of mod_wsgi was compiled for python2.7.11, but I'm running python 2.7.12.

I have read several responses to similar issues but I can't seem to find a solution. Partially because I'm not certain I understand the problem. I tried installing through python because [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) seemed to suggest there is a new way to get the mod. Doing this installed mod_wsgi4.5.7 (I specified with pip), yet my apache log is saying it's running mod_wsgi4.3.0.

Any help would be much appreciated.
--Edit--
Asked about Error: Pointing local browser to {server address}:8000 yields:
This site can’t be reached

```
192.168.1.120 refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: You forgot to say what the error is.

Comment: This is the error the browser displayed. I only assumed the message in my apache error log was related.